# start recording stream on button click with VLC dot net library

Tags: c#-4.0, libvlc

i have got a win form application that stream video from a ip camera...
i use a lib that is already avaliable..
lib site
VideoLan DotNet for WinForm, WPF & Silverlight 5

in order to stram the video i do this:

```
string path = "rtsp://****:****@192.168.5.223/profile2/media.smp";
LocationMedia media = new LocationMedia(path);
vlcControl1.Media = media;
vlcControl1.Play();
```

what i want now is to save the stream to a file on a button click, i mean , the video is playing, and then i press the button to record the video...

How can i do it?

when starting the video i can do this to save..

```
 string path = ....
 LocationMedia media = new LocationMedia(path);        media.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=file,mux=ogg,dst=C:\\Users\\hsilva\\Desktop\\123.mp4}");
 vlcControl1.Media = media;
 vlcControl1.Play();
```

so how can i add option if the video is already playing...

Comment: so, what i did was to stop the video that was playing , and then start the new video with the sout option.but i am currently trying to find the complete code where this code is done and then i will post it here.

Comment: Many thanks.  I have come up with the same process,  stopping and then starting,  with a #duplicate  instruction so the preview is rendered as well.  A bit clunky,  but better than nothing.

Comment: sorry for the delay. i could be much of a helper..when i did this code the thought was the same, better that nothing..

Comment: I know I'm kinda late, but could you post some code with the `sout option` ? Or any links to where i could find examples of working code that launches/stops recording of a stream?

Comment: it was a long time ago, but the sout option is in the example above. i will try to find the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using libVlc and just stumbled on your question and answers.
I took a similar approach but I also grabbed the `time(libvlc_media_player_get_time(IntPtr p_mi))` when I clicked on the `record (start)` button. I then used that time as the start `time(libvlc_media_player_set_time(IntPtr p_mi, Int64 newTime))` to resume playback and begin recording.

In my implementation, clicking on the record button again stops the recording, gets and sets the time, and resumes playing of the video on the screen.

The drawback to this approach is a noticeable delay in resumption of play, only a second or so, but not seamless as I had hoped. I suspect this is due to having to seek to the specified time.

I also found some references to `libvlc_media_player_record_[start|stop](IntPtr p_mi,...)` api's but nothing official.
I am interested in finding out if you were able to find a better way to accomplish this and how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

see there: https://mykb.cipindanci.com/archive/SuperKB/4164/ 
for RTSP live streaming, just do it like below:

```
IntPtr p_md = LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_get_media(this.libvlc_media_player_);
LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_add_option(p_md, pMrl);
LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_set_media(libvlc_media_player_, p_md);
LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_play(libvlc_media_player_);
```

and call below to stop recording:

```
IntPtr p_md = LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_get_media(this.libvlc_media_player_);
LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_set_media(libvlc_media_player_, p_md);
LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_play(libvlc_media_player_);
```

also that link demo two function:

```
LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_recorder_start(this.libvlc_media_player_, pMrl);
IntPtr pMrl = IntPtr.Zero;
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FILE_PATH);
pMrl = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length + 1);
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pMrl, bytes.Length);
Marshal.WriteByte(pMrl, bytes.Length, 0);
return LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_recorder_start(this.libvlc_media_player_, pMrl);
```

stop recording:

```
return LibVlcAPI.libvlc_media_player_recorder_stop(this.libvlc_media_player_);
```

libvlc_media_player_recorder_stop & libvlc_media_player_recorder_start only available in VLC x86 libs, not avaiable for x64 dlls.

but for file playing, you had to do it like BitMask777.